# If plugin is active show element. If not hide element

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

I'm using Wordpress with Mailchimp plugin.

I created this code into my footer.php file:

```
<div class="subscribe">
  <div class="subscribe-body">
    <h3>Subscribe</h3>
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[mc4wp_form id="2501"]' ); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying show code if the plugin is active, if plugin is inactive hide code.

I found manual for this on Wordpress, but I'm very beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can try is_plugin_active() Wordpress function.
In function.php write this by changing file path.

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Detect plugin. For use on Front End only.
     */
    include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
     add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_footer_code' );
     function add_footer_code(){
    // check for plugin using plugin name
    if ( is_plugin_active( 'plugin-directory/plugin-file.php' ) ) {
        //plugin is activated
?>

 <div class="subscribe">
  <div class="subscribe-body">
    <h3>Subscribe</h3>
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[mc4wp_form id="2501"]' ); ?>
  </div>

<?php
    } 
   }
```

Comment: your plugin folder name is `plugin-directory` and under folder main file of plugin is `plugin-file.php`

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_plugin_active/

Comment: you want to set after sepcific div then whole code write in footer.php file without add_action  and function

Answer (score 0):

How ?

```
/**
 * Detect plugin. For use on Front End only.
 */
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

// check for plugin using plugin name
if ( is_plugin_active( 'plugin-directory/plugin-file.php' ) ) {
 <div class="subscribe">
  <div class="subscribe-body">
    <h3>Subscribe</h3>
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[mc4wp_form id="2501"]' ); ?>
  </div>
 </div> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Correct Code**

```
   /**
     * Detect plugin. For use on Front End only.
     */
    include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_footer_code' );
    function add_footer_code(){
       // check for plugin using plugin name
       if ( is_plugin_active( 'plugin-directory/plugin-file.php' ) ) {?>

        <div class="subscribe">
           <div class="subscribe-body">
              <h3>Subscribe</h3>
              <?php echo do_shortcode( '[mc4wp_form id="2501"]' ); ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php
       } 
    }
```

**If you wanted to add condition in frontend, Use below code**

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

// check for plugin using plugin name
if ( is_plugin_active( 'plugin-directory/plugin-file.php' ) ) {
    //plugin is activated
}
```

**If you wanted to add condition in backend only, Use below code**

```
if ( is_plugin_active( 'plugin-directory/plugin-file.php' ) ) {
    //plugin is activated
}
```

**If you wanted to add condition in backend and frontend both, Use below code**

```
// check for plugin using plugin name
if(in_array('plugin-directory/plugin-file.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))){ 
    //plugin is activated
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! works great! How do I edit this code so that it does not appear in the footer, but under a certain <div> ??

Comment: Can u help me please ?

Comment: Instead of "wp_footer" hook, you need to use appropriate hook. Let me know in details where exactly you need to add, i can suggest hook if there is any available.